# Are custom triggers possible in Azure Functions v3 using webjobssdk 3.0.16?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

trying to implement a Redis Pub/Sub Functions Trigger that would trigger on when a message is published on a specified channel.

I've managed to write one following [this guide](https://github.com/yuka1984/SampleProjects/tree/master/SlackMessageTriggerExtention) (it's and old example using .net 4.6.1) but I've got stuck on the [class that implements IExtensionConfigProvider](https://github.com/yuka1984/SampleProjects/blob/master/SlackMessageTriggerExtention/SlackMessageTriggerExtention/SlackMessageExtentionConfig.cs) as the Config property is not exposed anymore in webjobssdk v3 and I can't find another why to register the extension. If I use `AddBindingRule` it moans saying that the provided binding provider doesn't implement `IBindingProvider` (it implements `ITriggerBindingProvider` in fact).
After some digging around on the web I couldn't manage to understand if custom triggers are even possible on Functions V3 (netstandard2.0) using webjobssdk 3.x

Any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it is actually possible to register the trigger by doing:

```
context.AddBindingRule<RedisTriggerAttribute>().BindToTrigger(new RedisTriggerAttributeBindingProvider());
```

Just tested and the trigger gets registered correctly.